# Can't create foreign key even when data type of both tables and engine are same?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have the following mysql table structue

This is the structure of 1st table:

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adv_publish` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `advertise_id` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `createdat` datetime NOT NULL,
      `removedat` datetime NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

This is the structure of 2nd table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adv_analytics` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `publish_advertiser_id` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

This is the foreign key relationship between two tables. When I execute, I get this error message:

## 1005 - Can't create table 'hotels.#sql-b80_155' (errno: 150)

```
ALTER TABLE adv_analytics ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_advertise_id (publish_advertiser_id) REFERENCES adv_publish(advertise_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Both table are currently empty.  Please find out the contradiction in my code. It's a bit urgent. Thank you for all your support.

Comment: 'hotels' is the name of the database, Mosty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented under [Using `FOREIGN KEY` Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan.

Therefore you must first create an index over `adv_publish.advertise_id`:

```
ALTER TABLE adv_publish ADD INDEX (advertise_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because it must reference a PRIMARY KEY (or UNIQUE index) and the script you wrote references advertise_id instead of id which is the primary key.

Comment: Wow, thank you, Eggyal and Lukos. It's awesome and working. Please someone mark the answer as accepted. I don't  have enough reputation.

Comment: @webblover: *Only* you are capable of accepting answers to your own questions.

Comment: eggyal, it's okay. I understand.